# How to increase size of field in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am managing a website and i got the following issue:

I cannot insert more than 64 KB of content in a record inside a database table (MySQL database).

How can i increase the size of that specific record so that it can accept more content?

Cheers!!

Comment: What type of content ? Look at the available types, some are bigger.

Comment: First off, what are you attempting to store in the record? Secondly, as @dystroy states there are a wide variety of types - [LONGBLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) can store 4GB if you *really* need to use this approach.

Comment: hello and thanks for replying! i am just inserting normal text from the website's administration backend. after i reach 64 KB on the record size, it stops adding text

Comment: I've edited your title a bit. StackOverflow is not the place where you are gonna get a detailed guide on how to use phpmyadmin. Find a guide on the rest of the internet if needed. Assuming you know what table you have to alter, you should have enough information with the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the Datatype `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB` in mysql.

You may also be interested to check out [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

On a side note(From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)):-

> Prior to MySQL 5.0.3, a VARCHAR column with a length specification
>   greater than 255 is converted to the smallest TEXT type that can hold
>   values of the given length. For example, VARCHAR(500) is converted to
>   TEXT, and VARCHAR(200000) is converted to MEDIUMTEXT. However, this
>   conversion affects trailing-space removal.

Comment: @user145969:- You are welcome. And if my answer helped you in any sense do accept that as an answer!!! :)

Comment: yes it wa your answer and i have upvoted it and marked it as the correct one

Comment: @user145969:- You have still marked the answer of Sumurai8 as accepted answer. Anyways not an issue.!!! Main thing is your issue is resolved.Happy coding!!! :)

Comment: @user145969:- If Rahul Tripathi's answer helped you then you must accept that as answer as a disciplinary action.!!! Although its your personal choice but since you accepted above so it would be good see this as an accepted answer!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the `TEXT` or `BLOB` type for your database field. That type accepts up to 64kb of data. You can use the `MEDIUMTEXT` or `MEDIUMBLOB` (16mb) or `LONGTEXT` or `LONGBLOB` (4gb) to increase the amount of data you can store in that field.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Comment: how can i convert an existing TEXT record into MEDIUMTEXT ?

Comment: @user145969:- You may probably want to do this:- **alter table foo modify column bar mediumtext;**

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to make a tutorial on how to use phpmyadmin (google is your friend!). Log into phpmyadmin, find the table you have to alter, find the field you want to insert more text into and change it's type to `MEDIUMTEXT` and save.

Comment: @Sumurai8 you are just rude mate.

Comment: @user145969 How is it rude? If I google "How to use phpmyadmin" it gives an extensive tutorial as first result. Tutorials on how to use a program are simply off-topic on StackOverflow.